# Created a view but lost privilege to underlying table afterwards

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

Say there is a relation Table(A, B, C) and I was given all privileges to it. I make a view V(A) viewing Table's A. Then if I am revoked of all privileges from the Table, what exactly happens to the view?

To my understanding, a view is a dynamically created abstraction of a table (if not materialized) when called. Since I do not have any privileges to the underlying table, I would not be able to call the view V, which needs SELECT privilege on the underlying table. So the view is essentially deleted from the system.

Is my understanding correct? What happens if the view is materialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not entirely correct. Pls note, however, that security models are different in all rdbms. Since you have put only mysql into the tag list, my answer will be mysql specific.

In mysql you can define the security model for a view using the SQL SECURITY option in the create view statement. This can be set to either DEFINER (user, who defined the view) or INVOKER (user, who executes the view). If it is set to definer, then mysql will check the access rights of the user, that defined the view, not those of the user, that executes it. If you have SUPER privilege, then you can use any user account as definer, not just your own.

Mysql checks if the definer or the invoker (based on the setting) has access to the underlying objects when a view is referenced. If a view uses the definer option and the definer has access to the underlying objects and you do not, the view will still give you the results.

See [access control for views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-security.html) in mysql documentation for details.

That being said, if you happen to have mysql v5.0.15 or earlier, then access rights to the underlying objects are checked only once: at the definition of the view.

Note: mysql does not support materialised views.